# 301 redirection for new site

Tags: php, html, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have migrated my wordpress site to html site.I want to redirect my wordpress url to existing html url.I have created .htaccess in my new html project file.

old url https://test.testproject.net/aboutus/rewards-and-recognitions.html
new url https://test.testproject.net/features/rewards-and-recognitions.html

old url https://test.testproject.net/events/upcoming-events-archive.html
new url https://test.testproject.net/events.html

old url https://test.testproject.net/product-overview/rewards-recognition.html
new url  https://test.testproject.net/features/rewards-recognition.html

old url https://test.testproject.net/features/
new url https://test.testproject.net/features.html

```
.htaccess
 ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.html
 Options -Indexes
  Redirect aboutus/rewards-and-recognitions.html  http://test.testproject.net/features/rewards-recognition.html   [R=301,L]
```

I have written my htaccess in the new html folder path for all old to new url.

```
Redirect aboutus/rewards-and-recognitions.html  http://test.testproject.net/features/rewards-recognition.html   [R=301,L] //shows forbidden error
```

how to write htaccess for all above url redirect from old to new

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect 301 [new_page] [old_page]
```

Open your .htaccess file. In the first value with square brackets type in the old page. In the second one, type in the new page. This will redirect the user to the new page upon accessing the site. In your case, you should type.

```
 Redirect 301 aboutus/rewards-and-recognitions.html 
 http://test.testproject.net/features/rewards-recognition.html
```